# How to make mysql return dataset in custom enconding?

Tags: mysql, encoding

The situation: there is a table with some default charset (e.g. ISO 8859-1).
Question: is it possible to make SELECT which returns the data in some other encoding? E.g. utf8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [SET NAMES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html) to specify the encoding of the requests. MySQL converts to that encoding all strings just before sending them to the client.

*Note that on the MySQL part the character sets and collations stay the same, so take care when working with them, because they won't be UTF8 until they're returned to the client.*

Comment: i'm so stupid!)) i was looking at this command for many times and could not understand, why it's not working for me? looks like the error was in my DNA-code)) i was specifying table default charset in "SET NAMES" clause instead of target charset (utf8)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT CONVERT(your_column_name AS utf8) FROM your_table

Comment: that's good, but not exactly what i've meant. i can't modify SQL query for some reason. i'm looking for simpliest solution. Something like 'execute some quety like "SET RESULT CHARSET utf8" before my original query and it will convert all char data to utf8 on the fly'

Comment: @heximal It's called `SET NAMES` :). See the link in my response. Also even if you convert in the SELECT to UTF8 it will be converted further to whatever the connection encoding is just before sending it to the client. You should use CONVERT only when working with the string in the query part.

Comment: Why don't you swap encoding in the underlying language you use to parse the dataset then?

Comment: Thank you Michael for your suggestions, but encoding dataset within underlying scripting language (php in my case) is more expensive than doing the same with native db-mecahnisms